# How to fetch facebook users page like information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any Graph API who provide the user likes information activites  on facebook.
I have a task, in this I need to fetch list of  pages that is liked by the facebook user and need to update in our DB in every 7 days.

Comment: what do you mean by `profile data of the users (likes) on facebook`

Comment: Basically, If user likes any page on facebook after that  if he login on my website through facebook, want to fetch all user's like activity  , so that I can store on our local db.

Comment: @Sahil: Did you get my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are searching for:

```
$facebopok->api("USER_ID/likes");
```

You can try in [API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Flikes).

Comment: I also got the information from fb docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes

Comment: is there a way to get all likes information after a given timestamp?

Comment: Yes, use `fql` and provide the condition on `created_time` in `WHERE` clause

Comment: I am not using fql, I am using direct Graph api in our code.

Comment: Then use it. You may refer this : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/12243242/1343690

Comment: thanks for your help, but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22312/discussion-between-invincible-and-sahil)